# Joguinho de Combate Python

Tags: python

Sou iniciante em programação e estou tentando fazer um simples joguinho para aplicar meu conhecimento sobre condicionais,repetição e o módulo Random, mas estou tendo alguns problemas de semântica.

Meu objetivo é atacar o monstro com um número aleatório entre 1 e 6, até que o *HP* dele  reduzir para um valor igual ou menor que zero e ao fazer isso indicar que o monstro foi vencido, mas estou tendo basicamente dois problemas:

- Quero que o jogador tenha a opção de atacar ou não e apresentar uma mensagem no caso em que ele decida não atacar.

- Quero apresentar uma mensagem de vitória, que apareça somente quando o jogador vencer o o monstro.

**Eis o código:**

```
from random import randint
print('Um monstro apareceu !')
hp=10
a=randint(1,6)
while hp-a>0:
  hp=hp-a
  d=input('Deseja atacar o monstro (S/N) ? ')
  if d=='S':
    print(hp-a,)
  if hp<=0:
    print('Você venceu o monstro !')
if d=='N':
  print('Você fugiu !')
```

O problema é que a mensagem de vitória não está sendo apresentada e a mensagem que indica que o jogador não quer atacar está aparecendo sempre. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basicamente tens 3 problemas principais:

1. > a=randint(1,6)

Esta Linha só acontece uma vez antes do ciclo while, logo o valor de `a` não vai mudar, isto parece-me que deveria estar dentro do ciclo e ser logo a primeira coisa a fazer quando o utilizador responda `'S'`.

2. Estás a decrementar vezes demais `a` a `hp`, o que pode levar a falsos dados serem mostrados, a à lógica estar bugada:

> while hp-a>0:
>   ...
>   hp=hp-a
>   ...
>   print(hp-a)

3. Quanto a "**mensagem de vitória não está sendo apresentada**" tem a ver também com o ponto 2, quando é feita a verificação `while hp-a>0` ele sai do loop sem que `hp=hp-a`, e por isso nem entra no `if hp<=0:` quando realmente `hp <= 0`.

Dito isto, podes simplificar para:

```
from random import randint

hp = 10
while hp > 0:
    d = input('Deseja atacar o monstro (S/N) ? ')
    if(d == 'S'):
        a = randint(1,6)
        hp = hp - a # novo valor do hp
        print('ataque de {} pontos, {} de hp restante do monstro'.format(a, hp)) # imprimir hp restante
    else:
        print('Você fugiu !')
        break
else: # se saiu do ciclo while sem haver break e porque o monstro ficou com hp <= 0
    print('Você venceu o monstro !')
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/CloseDownrightBullfrog)

Comment: Considere adicionar uma explicação do porquê do não funcionamento da aplicação do OP, visto que ele está a usar aplicação para aplicar conhecimentos dos ciclos e condições de python. Tirando isso boa resposta +1

Comment: @lazyFox, estava nesse momento a acrescentar isso, resposta editada. Vou sair do computador agora, caso vejas que falta/melhorar és bem vindo para editar a minha resposta. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Adicionei a vez do monstro no joguinho

```
from random import randint

hpm = 10 #Hp monstro
hpg = 10 # Hp guerreiro
while hpm > 0 and hpg > 0:
    d = input('Deseja atacar o monstro (S/N) ? ')
    if(d == 'S' or 's'):
        a = randint(1,6)
        hpm = hpm - a # novo valor do hp_mosntro
        print('ataque de {} pontos, {} de hp restante do monstro'.format(a, hpm)) # 
imprimir hp restante
        #Vez do monstro
        if (hpm <= 0):
            break
        b = randint(1,6)
        hpg = hpg - b # novo valor do hp_guerreiro
        print(f'O monstro te acertou com {b} pontos, você ainda tem {hpg} pontos de vida')

    else:
        print('Você fugiu !')
        break
if (hpm <= 0):
    print('Você venceu !')
else:
    print("Você foi derrotado!!!")
```